# SQL - Find records with similar value

Tags: sql

I have a table called "Tasks". This table has the following fields

- ID
- TypeID
- Description

How do I find all of the tasks that have more than one task of a TypeID? I do not have a TypeID to query with. Rather, I just want to list that tasks that have a TypeID that is used across multiple tasks. I'm not sure how to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tasks
WHERE TypeID IN
    (SELECT TypeID FROM Tasks
     GROUP BY TypeID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.description
    FROM TASKS t
GROUP BY t.description
  HAVING COUNT(t.typeid) > 1
```

Comment: Grouping by ID is bad - you are grouping on a unique key (most likely), and therefore there is never going to be a group with have having count > 1

Comment: This query is assuming that the Description-to-TypeID is 1-to-1... but I think he gets the idea now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do it without using group by:

```
# faster solution
SELECT A.*
FROM Tasks A,
     Tasks B
WHERE B.id != A.id AND B.TypeID = A.TypeID
```

## OR

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Tasks A,
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Tasks B WHERE B.id != A.id AND B.TypeID = A.TypeID)
```